# Unreasonably slow apps script when accessing data from a google sheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this simple script :

```
function counter() {
  var time1 = new Date();
  function debugme(text){
    var time2= new Date();
    var timeval = time2.getTime() - time1.getTime();
    Logger.log(text +" : "+timeval+" ms")
    time1 = new Date();
  }

  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  debugme("get sheet");
  var firstrow = Sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  debugme("get cell data");
}
```

**output :**

```
get sheet : 6 ms
get cell data : 27142 ms
```

I only try to get data from a cell but the **get cell data : 27142 ms** is just very slow. I have lot of formula in my sheet but that B3 has no formula (static value). Does anyone have any clue what cause this problem ?

EDIT :

Here's the link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KmJKGZscvzUbS7y7trsaE1vcbpYsSB0yQ_A63yEdeA0/edit?usp=sharing

Just press the BIG RED BUTTON to execute script.

Comment: I just tried your counter on my sheet an it gives me about 110--120 ms to get the cell data. It looks like the problem with your sheet, indeed. But it's impossible to investigate the problem further since you didn't provide your sheet.

Comment: Consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, in order to reproduce this.

Comment: I second the motion to share your sheet. As a guess it might just be really heavy, but it's only a guess until we see what we are dealing with.

Comment: Sorry i added new link in my post. I remove a lot of sheets and data, it's a bit faster than previous one but still very slow. Just press red big button to run the script.

Answer (score 1):

Your sheet is very bulky, just loading it took in my case more than one minute.

### I deleted in a copy of your spreadsheet all the empty rows below row 98 and this alone reduced the execution time for me from 20468 ms to 542 ms.

I can see erroneous formulas in column AD, and there can be other things slowing your script down - like other formulas, data validation, protected ranges etc.

I recommend you to either delete all redundant cells in your existing spreadsheet or - even better - copy all still relevant data (contents only) into a new spreadsheet.

Your code per se should not take much more than 500 ms to execute in a reasonably simple spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, this might be a problem specific to your sheet. However, accessing the data of a sheet is often slower than doing a `sheet.getDataRange().getValues()` and then accessing your values from the Array you get from it.
It's especially useful if you need to access values at several points in your code, or if you want to loop through a sheet.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Sorry i added new link in my post. I remove a lot of sheets and data, it's a bit faster than previous one but still very slow. Just press red big button to run the script.